# スプレッドシートを使用する宣言は、常にどのファイルでも行う必要がありますか？

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

情報を消すプログラムと、情報をコピーするプログラムを作成しましたが、`SpreadsheetApp.getActive();` の宣言を関数に入れて、メソッドに入れても機能しませんでした。
それぞれの関数内で変数を宣言すると、同じコードでも機能しました。
　　　
メソッド内に関数を入れられないのであれば、`SpreadsheetApp.getActive();` の宣言は常にすべての関数内で行う必要がありますか？

[今回使っているスプレッドシート](https://script.google.com/u/0/home/projects/1Jmg93inDWmFLYOuLW4lUbxK6HKGSxFugw0SYdqRCanfAqnAHQ4KKa67z/edit)

以下がコードおよびファイルです。

情報を消す関数

```
function Delete() {
  Sheet 
  //スプレッドシートアプリを開く
  var sheet1 = setActiveSheet(Sheet.getSheetByName('シート1'), true);
  sheet1.getRange('A2:B10').clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  spreadsheet.getRange('A2').activate();
  //情報を削除した後、A2をアクティブにする
  
};
```

情報をコピーする関数

```
function Copy() {
  Sheet
  var sheet1 = setActiveSheet(Sheet.getSheetByName('シート1'), true);
  sheet1.getRange('!C2:D10').activate().copyTo(destination, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL);;
  //C2からD10の情報をコピーする
}

SpreadsheetApp.getActive();を関数に入れるファイル
function Sheet(spreadsheet) {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
}
```

Comment: 「メソッド内に関数を入れる」という表現を使っている点・単純に掲載されているコードのみだと手元では動作確認が不可能な点から、コード片のみしか掲載できていないように思えます。
一度「【機能する】というコードの全体」と「【実際にやりたいが出来ない】コードの全体」を掲載するようにしたほうが良いと感じました。